# Does java support duplicate subpattern group number in regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get a single match with regex which contains both parts of the string at once like "BERPAR" in the following text:

`{"from":"BER", "comment":"something", "to":"PAR" }`

I came up with this `(?|from":"([A-Z]{3})"|to":"([A-Z]{3})")`, which apparently works fine with PCRE as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/iGVEFz/1)

But in the code, I get an error with Java compiler.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 2
(?|from":"([A-Z]{3})"|to":"([A-Z]{3})")
```

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String str = "{\"from\":\"BER\", \"comment\":\"something\", \"to\":\"PAR\" }";
        System.out.println(str);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?|from\":\"([A-Z]{3})\"|to\":\"([A-Z]{3})\")");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        while(m.find()) {
            results.add(m.group(1));
        }
        System.out.println(results);
     }
}
```

link to the online ide to see the error: http://tpcg.io/DWoebEWG

any solution or workaround would be appreciated.

Please note that the objective is **Only use regex. It's first matching group should return "BERPAR"**

PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS REGEX IS SUPPOSED TO BE PARSED BY A JAVA APPLICATION I DO NOT HAVE ANY OPTION TO WRITE JAVA CODE FOR IT!

THE ABOVE CODE SNIPPET IS FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSE ONLY!

Comment: Instead of trying to make regex work against JSON, instead considering learning how to use a library like GSON, which can properly parse JSON content for you.

Comment: Capture groups can only hold contiguous text (substrings). Could you work with a regex that converted parts of the string to empty strings, leaving "BERPAR"?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for your contribution. That regex supposed to be parsed by a java application, so using a third-party library or even other java mechanism is not an option for my case.

Comment: GSON is a Java library.  Any reason why you can't use it?

Comment: @CarySwoveland no, unfortunately, I don't have such an option.

Comment: You claim that "the first matching group" must return `BERPAR` but that string does not exist in the input and the link you showed for PCRE returns **2 matches** with one group each, so it **ALSO** doesn't return `BERPAR`.

Answer (score 1):

> Please note that the objective is Only use regex. It's first matching
> group should return "BERPAR"

You can get it by using `((?<=from\":\")|(?<=to\":\"))([A-Z]{3})(?=\")` as the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/iGVEFz/5).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "{\"from\":\"BER\", \"comment\":\"something\", \"to\":\"PAR\" }";
        System.out.println(str);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((?<=from\":\")|(?<=to\":\"))([A-Z]{3})(?=\")");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        while (m.find()) {
            results.add(m.group());
        }
        System.out.println(results);

        // Join the strings of the list
        String joined = String.join("", results);
        System.out.println(joined);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{"from":"BER", "comment":"something", "to":"PAR" }
[BER, PAR]
BERPAR
```

Comment: `[from|to]` does not match either `from` or `to`, but a char from `orfm|ot` set.

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew for suggesting the valuable correction. I've incorporated the same.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash sorry but that's not the correct answer, because it creates 2 matching groups. That's why you needed to use `String.join` to create the "BERPAR" string. The correct regex WOULD NOT NEED THAT PART. It should create "BERPAR" in the first matching group.